# Iterating over global keymap, removing all bindings to super keys

Tags: elisp

**Background**

Emacs on OS X by default binds several keys with the <kbd>super</kbd> modifier. I do not want these bindings as I switch between OS X and Windows frequently, and want a clean slate on both platforms to bind <kbd>super</kbd> keys for my own purposes.

**Code**

*global-unset-all-super-key.el*

```
(defun global-unset-all-super-key ()
  "Will unset any single key in global keymap that has the super
modifier."
  (let ((km (current-global-map)))
    (while km
      (let ((maybe-event (and (listp (car km))
                              (caar km))))
        (if (and (eventp maybe-event) ; Also filters out maybe-event
                                      ; when nil because (car km) was not a list.
                 (memq 'super (event-modifiers maybe-event)))
            (global-unset-key (vector maybe-event))))
      (setq km (cdr km)))))

(provide 'global-unset-all-super-key)
```

Lines added to *init.el*.

```
;; Remove default super bindings on Mac systems.
;; Do this early, before any mappings are added.
(when (string-equal system-type "darwin")
  (require 'global-unset-all-super-key)
  (global-unset-all-super-key))
```

**Questions**

1. Is this reasonably idiomatic lisp?
2. Are there elisp constructs that would simplify the implementation?
3. Are there elisp constructs that would make the implementation clearer?
4. And finally, is `(while <list> <body> (setq <list> (car <list>)))` the best that can be done to loop over a list taking each element in turn and doing something for side effects? `map` doesn't seem like a reasonable alternative because I'm not trying to build up a list to return. Something like Clojure's [`doseq`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq).

Comment: 4. you want `dolist`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using `dolist` as mentioned by @brfennpocock it looks mostly
fine.

`system-type` is a symbol though, so you can compare it with `eq`
instead of `string-equal` (unless I missed a reason to use that here).

Also the single `if` can also be `when` for consistency.

```
(defun global-unset-all-super-key ()
"Will unset any single key in global keymap that has the super modifier."
(dolist (km (current-global-map))
    (let ((maybe-event (and (listp (car km)) (caar km))))
    (when (and (eventp maybe-event)
                (memq 'super (event-modifiers maybe-event)))
        (global-unset-key (vector maybe-event))))))
```

For `init.el` if you have more functions also consider the
[autoload](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html)
facilities, but that's not necessary for just this bit of code (actually
I'd probably put it all in `init.el` to be honest even though a separate
file like this is somewhat cleaner).